# Simple LWJGL program renders nothing

Tags: opengl, java, shaders, lwjgl

When I run the following basic LWJGL program, all I get is a red screen due to `glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1)`. Nothing renders in the screen except the red background. I'm using Ubuntu as my operating system.

How do I fix this? Here is the complete source code.

Main.java:

```
import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.ContextAttribs;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.PixelFormat;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        createDisplay(1280, 720);

        //Initializations...

        float[] vertex = {
            -1.5f, 1.5f, 0f,    //V0
            -1.5f, -1.5f, 0f,   //V1
            1.5f, -1.5f, 0f,    //V2
            1.5f, 1.5f, 0f      //V3
        };

        int[] index = {
                0, 1, 3,
                3, 1, 2
        };

        Render render = new Render(vertex, index);

        Shader shader = new Shader("vertexShader", "fragmentShader"); //initialize shader   

        shader.bindAttribute(0, "positions");   
        shader.link();

        GL11.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);


        while(!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
            Display.sync(60);
            GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);     
            render.draw(shader);
            Display.update();
        }

        render.cleanUp();
        shader.cleanUp();
        Display.destroy();
    }

    private static void createDisplay(int Width, int Height) {
        ContextAttribs attribs = new ContextAttribs(3, 2);
        attribs.withForwardCompatible(true).withProfileCore(true);

        try {
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(Width, Height));
            Display.create(new PixelFormat(), attribs);
        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("Cannot Create Display");
        }

        GL11.glViewport(0, 0, Width, Height);
    }
}
```

Render.java:

```
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30;

public class Render {

    int vaoID;
    int vertexCount;
    List<Integer> vbos = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public Render(float[] vertex, int[] indices) {
        vaoID = createVAO();
        addIndices(indices);
        addVertex(vertex);
        unbindVAO();
        vertexCount = indices.length;
    }

    public void draw() {
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(vaoID);
        GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL11.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, vertexCount, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
    }

    public void draw(Shader shader) {
        shader.bind();
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(vaoID);      
        GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);  
        GL11.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, vertexCount, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);     
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
        shader.unbind();
    }

    public void cleanUp() {
        for(int vbo: vbos) {
            GL15.glDeleteBuffers(vbo);
        }
        GL30.glDeleteVertexArrays(vaoID);
    }

    public int getvaoID() {
        return vaoID;
    }

    private int createVAO() {
        int id = GL30.glGenVertexArrays();
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(id);
        return id;
    }

    private void addVertex(float[] vertex) {
        addToAttribList(0, vertex);
    }

    private void addToAttribList(int slot, float[] buffer) {
        int vboID = GL15.glGenBuffers();
        vbos.add(vboID);
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
        FloatBuffer float_buffer = toFloatBuffer(buffer);
        GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, float_buffer, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        GL30.glVertexAttribIPointer(slot, 3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    }

    private void addIndices(int[] indices) {
        int vboID = GL15.glGenBuffers();
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
        IntBuffer int_buffer = toIntBuffer(indices);
        GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, int_buffer, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    }



    private FloatBuffer toFloatBuffer(float[] buffer) {
        FloatBuffer floatBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(buffer.length);
        floatBuffer.put(buffer);
        floatBuffer.flip();
        return floatBuffer;

    }

    private IntBuffer toIntBuffer(int[] buffer) {
        IntBuffer intBuffer = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(buffer.length);
        intBuffer.put(buffer);
        intBuffer.flip();
        return intBuffer;

    }

    private void unbindVAO() {
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);

    }

}
```

Shader.java:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20;

public class Shader {
    private final int programID;
    private int vertexID;
    private int fragmentID;

    public Shader(String keyVertex, String keyFragment) {
        programID = createProgram();
        vertexID = createVertexShader(keyVertex);
        fragmentID = createFragmentShader(keyFragment);
    }

    public int createProgram() {
        int id = createProgramShader();
        if(id==0) {
            System.err.println("Cannot create shader");
        }
        return id;
    }

    public int createVertexShader(String key) {
        int id = createShader("shaders/" + key + ".vs", GL20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        if(id == 0) {
            System.err.println("Error creating Vertex Shader");
        }
        return id;
    }

    public int createFragmentShader(String key) {
        int id = createShader("shaders/" + key + ".fs", GL20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        if(id == 0) {
            System.err.println("Error creating Fragment Shader");
        }
        return id;
    }

    public void link() {
        GL20.glLinkProgram(programID);
        GL20.glValidateProgram(programID);
    }

    public void bind() {
        GL20.glUseProgram(programID);
    }

    public void unbind() {
        GL20.glUseProgram(0);
    }

    public void cleanUp() {
        GL20.glDetachShader(programID, vertexID);
        GL20.glDetachShader(programID, fragmentID);
        GL20.glDeleteShader(vertexID);
        GL20.glDeleteShader(fragmentID);
        GL20.glDeleteProgram(programID);
    }

    public void bindAttribute(int attribute, String variableName) {
        GL20.glBindAttribLocation(programID, attribute, variableName);
    }

    private int createProgramShader() {
        return GL20.glCreateProgram();
    }

    private int createShader(String key, int type) {
        StringBuilder shaderSource = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(key));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        String line;
        try {
            while((line = reader.readLine())!=null) {
                shaderSource.append(line).append("\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int id = GL20.glCreateShader(type);
        GL20.glShaderSource(id, shaderSource);
        GL20.glCompileShader(id);
        if(GL20.glGetShaderi(id, GL20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == 0) {
            System.err.println(key + ": Shader compilation error: " + GL20.glGetShaderInfoLog(id, 1080));

        }
        GL20.glAttachShader(id, programID);
        return id;
    }



}
```

And here are the shaders..

vertexShader.vs:

```
#version 400 core

in vec3 positions;

out vec3 pass_pos;

void main(void) {
    gl_Position = vec4(positions, 1.0);
    pass_pos = vec3(positions.x, 1.0, positions.z+0.05);
}
```

fragmentShader.fs:

```
#version 400 core

in vec3 pass_pos;

out vec4 out_Color;

void main(void) {
    out_Color = vec4(pass_pos, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: OS is not relevant. What's your hardware?

Comment: Intel® Core™ i3-5005U CPU @ 2.00GHz × 4

Comment: Intel® HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2)

Comment: And 8 GB of Ram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spotted error:

```
GL20.glAttachShader(id, programID);
```

Should be:

```
GL20.glAttachShader(programID, id);
```

And,

```
GL30.glVertexAttribIPointer(slot, 3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
```

Should be:

```
GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(slot, 3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
```